# 301 redirect phpbb forum and all subpages

Tags: redirect, forum, phpbb

Hello I would like to redirect all my website/forum/ and all subpages (e.g.: /forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=453) to my index page.

I have tried a few different methods but they do not work.

I tried RedirectMatch 301 ^/forum/.*$ http://myhomepage.com but it leaves part of the forum page in the url.

I also tried: 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/forum/.*$ http://myhomepage.com [L,R=301]

but that did nothing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For Apache's `httpd.conf`,

Try using `RewriteRule ^/forum/(.*)$ http://myhomepage.com/ [R,NC]`

The `(.*)` should catch anything that comes after `/forum/`. The `R` means redirect, and `NC` means case insensitive.